# how do I access this jQuery variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following [code](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) in my project that helps me do some very funky AJAX uploading.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            action: "{% url ... %}",
            element: $('#file-uploader')[0],
            multiple: true,
            onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                if(responseJSON.success) {
                    alert("success!");
                } else {
                    alert("upload failed!");
                }
            },
            onAllComplete: function(uploads) {
                // uploads is an array of maps
                // the maps look like this: {file: FileObject, response: JSONServerResponse}
                alert("All complete!");
            },
            params: {
                'csrf_token': '{{ csrf_token }}',
                'csrf_name': 'csrfmiddlewaretoken',
                'csrf_xname': 'X-CSRFToken',
                'iID': '{{ itemID }}',
                'received': $('letter_received').val(),
                'is_company': $('letter_is_company').val(),
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

The only problem is I want to pass additional GET values to the server. I have tried the above but the script gets executed when the page opens, not when the values change. In the link above under '*Sending additional params*' the author recommends adding additional values at runtime by using the following code:

```
uploader.setParams({
   anotherParam: 'value'
});
```

I just don't know how I can access the `uploader` variable. Take the following for example:

```
<button onclick="update_uploader(1,0)">
...
<script>
    function update_uploader(received,is_company) {
        uploader.setParams({
            received: received,
            is_company: is_company
        });
    }
</script>
```

I can't access `uploader` because of scope issues. *[and yes I have tried declaring `uploader` outside of `$(function(){` but it breaks the uploader :(]*

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean "declaring `uploader` outside"? and How does it break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `var uploader` to `uploader`. This will make your variable global.

Comment: Thank you, you were right. (It gets confusing having to flick between dojo and jquery)

Answer (score 0):

The uploader in your code is a local variable, if you want to access this variable outside de function() you must declare updloader as global variable (but this is almost never recomend, but is indeed out of scope here). To solve your problem just change:

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
        action: "{% url ... %}",
        ....
});
```

to

```
window.uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
        action: "{% url ... %}",
        ....
});
```

Then the uploader will be available globally in the page.

Comment: That will only work if the element is available. The variable can be global but still initialized after the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put this code within a jQuery  $(function(){ block. Removing the first line and last line in your code should work.